# How to remove/disable menu contribution from CEditor ruler context menu of Eclipse?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

How to remove/disable menu contribution from CEditor ruler context menu of Eclipse? For example when i right click on Vertical ruler margin then it display menu like Toggle breakpoint, Add breakpoint , Add Dynamic printf etc So i want remove the Add Dynamic printf option. How I can Do this

Comment: You might be able to do something with the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point, but it will require research on your part.

Comment: Not like that . These option are coming from CDT plugin org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui So I want to disable  one of the menu contribution item without modifying  CDT side. Is it possible to get existing instance of the action class to disable action ? How to do this?